# Load Balance Queues for variable rate consumers

Tags: java, performance, distributed-computing

I have a producer and consumer framework. Each producer pushes to a queue and consumer consumes from the queue. At any point in time there can be one or more queues with each consumer consuming from single queue. But producer can produce to any queue. If a consumer is slow its keeps piling with messages. I am trying to come with a framework where i can load balance consumers so that all consumer queues have almost equal messages regardless of the consumers speed.

Example:

[image]

Here queues Q1-Q3 is supposed to have almost equal messages irrespective of the rate of C1-C3 consumers. Default policy now i am using is round robin for producers but if any consumer is slow it keep adding messages to queue. All messages are of the same type so it go to any of the queues.

Any suggestions to start with is helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is my solution i have implemented. Algorithm used is as below.

1. Every 30 seconds find mean of all queues.
2. If the lag of a
   consumer w.r.t mean in greater than a particular threshold ignore that
   queue/consumer.

Producer Code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Producer implements Runnable{

    private List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> blockingQueues = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> fullPartitions;
    private List<Integer> activePartitions;
    long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int THRESHOLD = 10000;
    int currentQueue = 0;

    public Producer(List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> blockingQueues, List<Integer> fullPartitions, List<Integer> activePartitions) {
        this.blockingQueues = blockingQueues;
        this.fullPartitions = fullPartitions;
        this.activePartitions = activePartitions;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true) {
            blockingQueues.get(getNextID()).offer(new Random().nextInt(100000));
            try {
                if(System.currentTimeMillis()-start<300000)
                    Thread.sleep(1);
                else
                    break;
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private int getNextID() {
        if(System.currentTimeMillis()-timer>30000) {
            activePartitions = new ArrayList<>();
            long mean = 0l; 
            for(int i=0;i<fullPartitions.size();i++) 
                mean += blockingQueues.get(i).size();

            mean  = mean/blockingQueues.size();
            for(int i=0;i<fullPartitions.size();i++) 
                if(blockingQueues.get(i).size()-mean<THRESHOLD)
                    activePartitions.add(i);

            timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
        int partitionID = activePartitions.get(currentQueue%activePartitions.size());
        currentQueue++;
        return partitionID;
    }
}
```

Consumer :

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class Consumer implements Runnable{

    private BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(100000000);
    private int delayFactor;
    public Consumer(BlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue, int delayFactor, int consumerNo) {
        this.blockingQueue = blockingQueue;
        this.delayFactor = delayFactor;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true) {
            try {
                blockingQueue.take();
                if(blockingQueue.isEmpty())
                    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis()-start)/1000);
                Thread.sleep(delayFactor);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Main Thread:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class KafkaLoadBalancer {

    private static int MAX_PARTITION = 4;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> blockingQueues = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> fullPartitions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        List<Integer> activePartitions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Creating Queues");
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_PARTITION;i++) {
            blockingQueues.add(new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000000));
            fullPartitions.add(i);
            activePartitions.add(i);
        }

        System.out.println("Starting Producers");
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_PARTITION;i++) {
            Producer producer = new Producer(blockingQueues,fullPartitions,activePartitions);
            new Thread(producer).start();
        }

        System.out.println("Starting Consumers");
        for(int i=0;i<MAX_PARTITION;i++) {
            Consumer consumer = new Consumer(blockingQueues.get(i),i+1,i);
            new Thread(consumer).start();
        }

        System.out.println("Starting Display Thread");
        DisplayQueue dq = new DisplayQueue(blockingQueues);
        new Thread(dq).start();
    }
}
```

DispayQueue : To display queue size

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

public class DisplayQueue implements Runnable {

    private List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> blockingQueues;

    public DisplayQueue(List<BlockingQueue<Integer>> blockingQueues) {
        this.blockingQueues = blockingQueues;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(true) {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis()-start>30000) {
                for(int i=0;i<blockingQueues.size();i++)
                    System.out.println("Queue "+i+" size is=="+blockingQueues.get(i).size());
                start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple - add to the queue with the lowest item count.

Comment: I have used the same logic and improvised it a bit using a timer. Please check.

Comment: @AmarendraReddy: it is a bad idea to have your code verified on SO. Not recommended. Just too many things that can be misinterpreted by the reader.